# Написать регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Имеются строчки вида:

```
(13450, 'example@mail.com', '$1$GgwhMNJU$w6s36fSX.nqapMk6gmR3O0', 'example@mail.com', 1533425876, 1533425876, '197.210.63.7', '--', '', 0, '', 0.000000, 0.00, 0, 0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00476175, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, '', '', '', '', '', NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, 0, 0),
(13451, 'example@mail.com', '$1$csfMy2l2$UXLFOyQzXfScA1SEFXuka1', 'example@mail.com', 1533427014, 1536375010, '174.199.10.145', '--', '', 0, '', 0.000000, 0.00, 0, 0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 13866.18432573, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, '', '', '', '', '', NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, 0, 0),
```

И так далее, таких строчк очень много. Требуется написать регулярку, чтобы строки пришли к этому:

```
(example@mail.com)
```

Убрал в начале от номера `^[(]([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]),`
Далее остается только правая часть. Буду благодарен за помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: Может, [`\(\d+,\s*'([^']+)'.*\),` => `($1)`](https://regex101.com/r/vDKzrO/1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

```
\(\d+,\s*'([^']+)'.*\),
```

и замените на `($1)`.

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/vDKzrO/1).

**Подробности**

- `\(` - открывающая скобка
- `\d+` - 1 и более цифр
- `,` - запятая
- `\s*` - 0 и более пробельных символов
- `'([^']+)'` - `'`, затем захватывающая группа №1: один и более символов, отличных от `'`, а потом снова `'`
- `.*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от символов перехода на новую строку
- `\),` - подстрока `),`

`($1)` заменяет совпадение круглыми скобками со значением захватывающей группы №1 внутри.